# Probability of number of rolls, sometime to do with pmf?

Tags: probability

> You roll a 6-sided die repeatedly. Starting with $i = 1$, let $R_i$ denote the result of roll $i$. If $R_i>i$, then you will roll again; otherwise you stop. Let $N$ denote the number of rolls.
>
> What is $P[N > 3]$?
>
> What is the PMF of $N$?

Own attempt: I attempted to use complements to count the value. $$P[N>3]=1-P[N<4]$$ I got $P[1] = \frac 16$ but subsequent values of $N$ I've no clue how to approach.

Comment: You can let $N$ denote the number of 'failures' (getting more than 1) before first 'success' (getting 1). So then your approach will work once you know the distribution for the discrete random variable $N$ (geometric).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @AnyAD I unsure of what you mean. Say the first roll is 5>1, the second roll can only be 6 else i stop the roll. How do i generalise the case and convert it into a probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit from $R_i > 1$ to $R_i > i$ changes a lot:

- The RV $N$ can assume only the values $i=1, \ldots , 6$.
- The tree diagram below reveals 
  $$P(N = i) = \frac{i}{6}\frac{5!}{6^{i-1}(5-(i-1))!}$$

[image: tree diagram]

Comment: notice: it is $R_i>i$, not $R_i>1$

Comment: Thanks. This was a later edit. Before it was $>1$. So the answer is not correct anymore.

Comment: Now, new answer after OP's edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Start by determining the PMF of $N$ and us this to find $\mathbb{P}(N > 3)$. For the first values of $N$ we have
$$ \mathbb{P}(N=1) = \mathbb{P}(R_1 = 1) = \frac{1}{6}$$ 
and 
$$ \mathbb{P}(N=2) = \mathbb{P}(R_1 > 1, R_2 \leq 2) = \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{2}{6} = \frac{10}{36} $$
The other values can be determined in a similar way and I leave this to you.